# How to restrict instance of Microsoft Word?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-word, office-automation

Using Office Automation, how can an instance of `Word` be opened so that, for example, the user is not able to invoke the `"Save As..."` command?

Answer (score 2):

Create an auto load template and remove the saveas command from the menu.

Comment: Can this be done on a per-instance basis?

Comment: Well you could only load template based on some rule